# Left Join to produce One Row for Each Day

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have two Tables one. One Employee_List( that has all the list of employee) and Attendance( That keeps a track of the attendance)
I am Using  a Grid to Display the Employee Information and a RadioButtonList that marks him Absent or Present.

```
SELECT Hcc_Emp_Detail.Hcc_Emp_Id, Emp_Attendance_Main.Emp_Attendance_Action, Emp_Attendance_Main.Emp_Attendance_Date
FROM  Emp_Attendance_Main INNER JOIN
               Hcc_Emp_Detail ON Emp_Attendance_Main.Emp_Attendance_Emp_Id = Hcc_Emp_Detail.Hcc_Emp_Id
```

The issue I am facing is If I mark the attendance for an employee on 26th ..and on 27th the grid is not empty. THat particular grid should be empty everyday.[image] and the join statement should show attendance of the already marked and keep the others empty. And there should be a fresh grid everyday.
Thank you.

[image]

This is the Empty grid of all the emp on 26th before taking attendance. 
[image]

This is how it looks after taking attendance.
[image]

Now when i login on the 27th to take the attendance the grid should turn empty with the list of all the employees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to do, just left join to emp attendance main with a criteria of date  -

```
SELECT hed.Hcc_Emp_Id, eam.Emp_Attendance_Action, eam.Emp_Attendance_Date
FROM  Hcc_Emp_Detail hed
LEFT JOIN Emp_Attendance_Main eam
    ON hed.Hcc_Emp_Id = eam.Emp_Attendance_Emp_Id 
      AND eam.Emp_Attendance_date=cast(getdate() as date)
```